# Creating preview and icon for screenshots

Tags: applescript, unix

I would like to make this code to automatically create preview and icon so it looks nice in Finder and so i don't have to wait my graphics app to create these things when i first time open in browse view. Thanks

```
do shell script "screencapture -Wimxo " & quoted form of ("/Users/Maccie/Desktop/shot.png")
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking here. To avoid getting answers that don't really solve your problem, the question will be closed FOR NOW until it can be improved. Please edit your question to make it clearer so we can reopen it. Read [How to Ask](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask) for more ideas to improve the question. Confusing questions are closed so they don't attract a scattering of answers before they're in a form that is likely to get a clear answer; your question can be reopened at any time if you or someone on your behalf suitably amends it.

Comment: Especially: What graphics are you using? Which browse view are you talking about, the one in Finder or the one in your graphics app?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work.

It uses your code to capture the image, although I have made it so any user can use it.

It then uses an edited version of a script I found on [macosxautomation](http://www.macosxautomation.com/applescript/imageevents/08.html) website for image events

```
set homeFolder to path to home folder
    set imageName to "shot.png"
    set saveFolderPath to homeFolder & "Desktop:" & imageName as string
    do shell script "screencapture -Wimxo " & quoted form of POSIX path of saveFolderPath
    --set the target_path to the saveFolderPath as Unicode text
    delay 1
    try
        tell application "Image Events"


            -- start the Image Events application
            launch
            -- open the image file
            set this_image to open saveFolderPath
            set type_ to file type of this_image
            -- save in same  file with icon
            save this_image as type_ in saveFolderPath with icon
            -- purge the open image data
            close this_image

        end tell
    on error error_message
        display dialog error_message buttons {"Cancel"} default button 1
    end try
```

Comment: Thanks this works, but... I take many times screenshots in **very** fast pace and i think using Image Events might be too slow especially because in my own old code there is additional code which is run between each shots so IE might slow it too much. Is there any way to change quality level of preview and icon? Does this additional save by Image Events affect to picture quality?

Comment: Hi, there most probably is. The only other way maybe using third party CLI like imagmagik http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php or exiftool http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/ if I had sometime I probably could look at writing something native but I think it would not be soon